# Using dependencies in a GNU makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu

I am having a doubt on how to use dependencies in my GNU makefile.
Consider the following make file:

```
// Building all my dependency files
$(OUTDIR)/%.dep: %.c
    $(DPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DPPFLAGS) $(@:dep=o) $< $@
```

Now, I have these dependency files containing lists or "pointer" to files/dependencies.

I then want to create my object files based on those dependencies (when they change).
Can I do the following thing:

```
$(OUTDIR)/%.o $(OUTDIR)/%.orc: %.c $(OUTDIR)/%.dep
   $(AS) $(COMMONFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Does that not however mean that I will be rebuilding my objects only when my *.dep files actually change (not the files listed within those dependency files).
Is that the correct way of doing it? If not, what is?
I feel like I am not using/understanding how these dependency files are being interpreted by the tools.

Comment: You may be interested to read this blog post to get more details on how dependency generation works with make: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/  I'm not sure if this will be sufficiently helpful.

Comment: @MadScientist, I did check that page, but did not really help me, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency files are themselves in makefile format, and is input to make, not gcc. To use them, you will need to include them in your makefile (ignoring the file if it hasn't been created yet):

```
-include $(wildcard *.dep)
```

The only caveat is that it will then build the dep files whenever it needs to build anything, including a "make clean", so you need to make the include conditional on the target:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(wildcard *.dep)
endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but considering my $(DPP) command is the one responsible for generating my .dep files, how can I "include" those files if they only get generated when invoking cs-make? Does it mean I am generating my dependencies in the wrong spot?

Comment: If you read the above-mentioned blog post section titled "The GNU make include directive" it explains this.

Comment: The first time you build you do not need the dependencies, as you will build everything anyway, so the best is probably to add a `-` prefix to the include to ignore the file if it has not been made yet. I will edit my answer to note that.